# Caldera Forms Manual formula

Tags: forms

I have small problem with caldera forms.i'm trying to count car quantity depenp on how many people will booking trip.Let's say 1-4 people,so its capacity of 1 car,but if 5 till 8 people so its 2 cars.how can i write this formula?i've been trying many things but nothing works.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The presumptions are the capacity of the car is constant (ie, 4) and the total number of people booking the trip is entered in a single number field. Add a calculation field and create a manual formula based on the total number of people booking the trip. The formula would be:

**ceil(%total_people%/4)** - where "total_people" is the slug for the total number of people field.